# Database structure for edited news

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a news tables as follows, when editing news I would like to see the original version of the news and edited versions of news by all the users how do i make database table structure for that ?

```
Table news
News id, title, headline, content, date, user
```

Comment: Editing means your going to create a new record (with new news id) or the same record going to be changed?

Comment: Do you need to track which version each editor started from? Multiple editors, e.g. Chico, Groucho, Gummo, Harpo and Zeppo, may be working from different starting versions at the same time and save their work in any order.

Comment: yes habo pls give me schema

Comment: I don't happen to have a design in my pocket, just wanted to clarify your requirements. It implies either: you provide the tool that edits news and maintain versions internally, you tag the files with the version in a reasonably tamperproof manner whenever someone requests an article to edit, or you have a check-out/check-in system like many source control packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The long answer is to learn about Time-Oriented Database Applications, there's a [web site](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/publications.html) that has an [eBook](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/tdbbook.pdf) about it.

The short version is to either have another table for the history or change you existing table to allow for history.

Think about how you would differentiate between "original version", "edited versions" and "most recent versions". It could be simply by date, or you could try to maintain your own version number column, or you might even want some kind of flag or bit field (I don't recommend this option).

**UPDATE**

One possible solution (hard to know the best one for your scenario, so just an example):

Keep your existing table for the most recent version, as that's what you will probably need most of the time.

Add another table for historical versions, and in code (or a SQL Trigger if you have to) copy the existing version to the history table before saving the update. The schema of your history table could look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NewsHistory]
(
    NewsHistoryID int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    NewsID int NOT NULL,
    Title varchar(100),
    Headline varchar(200),
    Content varchar(MAX),
    CreatedAt datetime NOT NULL,
    CreatedBy int NOT NULL
)
```

Just populate `NewsID, Title, Headline, Content, CreatedAt, CreatedBy` from the existing table before writing an update.

When you want to see the history for a news item, simply:

```
SELECT
    Title,
    Headline,
    Content,
    CreatedAt,
    CreatedBy
FROM NewsHistory
WHERE NewsID = @newsID
ORDER BY NewsHistoryID
```

Sort by date if you prefer, but natural ordering should work here if everything is inserted in the right order. Again, depends on your needs/environment.

Comment: can you give example schema pls ?

Comment: @ktm there you go, let me know if that suits your needs

Answer (score 0):

See, I suppose you want to track article's editing version, So use below schema for that.

```
NewsId,User,Title,HeadLine,Content,Status,PostType,UpdatedBy,UpdatedDate
```

Status contains enum like Published,Draft something.! So you can find published posts.

PostType contains enum like Revision,Final so you can find revision of any news article.

UpdatedBy contains user's Id who updates news & UpdatedDate contains date when post is updated.

Comment: How would i change schema if i want to save the edits in another table ?

Comment: I think enum is not supported in sql server

Comment: Why do you want to save edits in another table? If you want you can use SQL commands like 
`INSERT INTO Another_Table(C1,C2) Select C1,C2 from Table Where PostType='Revision'`

Then you need to manually delete those rows from Main table.!

Ya, Enum is not supported by SQL Server.So you have to use column like enum.! :)

Comment: So if I want to use the same table than i have to keep on adding new rows instead of editing with the same id right ?

Comment: Yes,Suppose news article has edited more than 2 people, then you are not able to find who edit last one? Also you will not find revisions after 2 UPDATEs.

Answer (score 0):

I’d go with pretty much identical table structure for history.

Table NewsHistory
News_History_ID, News id, Revision,  title, headline, content, date, user

News_ID would reference the latest version of the news in news table
Revision would be used to make tracking easier

What you can do is to create UPDATE trigger in your news table that will automatically copy current version into NewsHistory table.